# Restore database problems

Tags: akeneo

I have restored a backup of the DB back into the Akeneo PIM DB but it is now not showing me any products within the system.

The DB is connecting properly ie I can log in and the category tree is available, attribute lists etc but my products (500~) are not available in the Akeneo environment (0 products).  The data IS in the DB - I can query and view etc directly through SQL.

Anybody have any ideas?  What have I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Just got an answer from @gplanchat on the Akeneo Slack list with the solution.
I needed to reindex my catalog - something I haven't seen reference to in the documentation.  FOr others, this is what is needed:

```
bin/console akeneo:elasticsearch:reset-indexes --env=prod
bin/console pim:product:index --all --env=prod
bin/console pim:product-model:index --all --env=prod
```

Thanks to @gplanchat